# SQL query to show most ordered product

Tags: sql, mysql

I have this table structure

**Product**
product_id (PK)
name

**Order_Detail**
order_detail_id
product_id
quantity

**Example data**

Product  :
1 product1
2 product2
3 product3
4 product4
5 product5

Order_Detail  :
1 3 2
2 3 1
3 3 1
4 2 1
5 2 1
6 1 1
7 4 1
8 5 1
9 1 1
10 2 1
11 3 1

Please help me to get top 3 ordered product based on how many times the product ordered ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this migth work:

```
SELECT p.`product_id`, p.`name`, SUM(o.`quantity`) AS quantity
FROM `Order_Detail` AS o
    INNER JOIN `Product` AS p
    ON o.`product_id` = p.`product_id`
GROUP BY o.`product_id`
ORDER BY SUM(o.`quantity`) DESC, p.`name` ASC
LIMIT 3
```